# Use Typeface with EditText in widget

Tags: android, android-widget, typeface

Is it possible to use somehow `Typeface` font definition loaded from assets with `EditText` in widget ?

Comment: have you tired something for that?

Comment: I did it with converting font to the bitmap, but it's painful. I have tried setting custom `EditText` in widget's layout, but with no luck (even simple `CustomEditText extends EditText` with no content).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font you want to use needs to reside in the assets/fonts directory, and you access it like so:

```
Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
edittext.setTypeface(myFont);
```

Comment: As @Andro Selva asks in another answer - does it works with widgets ?

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/myfont.ttf"));
```

Assuming you have this structure of files:

/assets/fonts/myfont.ttf

Answer (score 0):

Please See below code for that, it will solve your problem.

```
// text view label
TextView mTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DroidSansFallback.ttf");

// Applying font
mTextView1.setTypeface(tf);
```

And see below link for more information.

[Android Development – Customize Android Fonts](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-development-customize-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Typeface tf   =    Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Comic.ttf");
 youredittext.setTypeface(tf);
```

I have tried this now. It worked for me. Good luck

Comment: Have you used it with widgets ? I mean `AppWidgetProvider`

Comment: no, but have you tried like this. if so is it not working to you?

Answer (score 0):

Other betther form to implement this and avoid to add the font to all the textviews is extends a TextView (or EditText or ... ) and apply the font on the setTypeface method. With this method you can control bold, italic and other styles.

Here is a code for a class that extends TextView and apply a Roboto font. Moreover it controls some bugs that Android 4.0 has with the html  codes when set an Spannable from an HTML

```
public class TextViewRoboto extends TextView {  
public static final String TAG = "TextViewRoboto";

public TextViewRoboto(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public TextViewRoboto(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TextViewRoboto(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {

    //This is to override eclipse error messages
    if (!super.isInEditMode()) {      

        if (style == Typeface.BOLD)  
            super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"));
        else if (style == Typeface.ITALIC)
            super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf"));
        else
            super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"));    
    }    
}


//
// With this code aboid the <b> and <strong> problem on Jelly Bean
//

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    try{
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        //Logger.w(TAG, "Problem onMeasure. Set normal text");
        setText(getText().toString());
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); 
    }
}   
@Override
public void setGravity(int gravity){
    try{
        super.setGravity(gravity);
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        //Logger.w(TAG, "Problem setGravity. Set normal text");
        setText(getText().toString());
        super.setGravity(gravity); 
    }
}
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    try{
        super.setText(text, type);
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        //Logger.w(TAG, "Problem on setText. Set normal text");
        setText(text.toString());
    }
}

public void setHTMLText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    String tmpText = text.toString();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        tmpText = tmpText.replace("<strong>", "<b>");
        tmpText = tmpText.replace("</strong>", "</b>");
        tmpText = tmpText.replace("<em>", "<i>");
        tmpText = tmpText.replace("</em>", "</i>");
        text = tmpText;
    }

    try{
        super.setText(Html.fromHtml(tmpText), type);
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        //Logger.w(TAG, "Problem on setText. Set normal text");
        setText(text.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
```

Comment: Read the question properly. He need custom font from assets

Comment: TypeFace provides fonts, isn't it??